# Want to change the adt plugin version of eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, java, adt

I installed Adt Plug in in eclipse.When i open eclipse i got a message that "This version Adt requires android sdk tools in revision 17 or above.Current revison is 8.How can i solve this issue.I want to work in android 2.3.Can anybody help me for this

Answer (score 0):

Just go to AVD manager in eclipse : and update your sdk to revision 17 or above.

check this link:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > select 4 adt plugins > update

Answer (score 0):

Window--> android SDK Manager-->select tools folder and click install 1 package.